# Selenium (java): Handling duplicate xpath from different tab

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

Need your help with below query:

My website is having tabbed structure, So I can open same page in Multiple Tabs.
Now issue with this is id becomes dynamic for every field w.r.t. its tab location.

For ex. id for one of the field

> **on Tab 3**
>
> tfgld4510m000 **-3-** grid-1-tfgld418.fitr-8-filter-value-control-widget
>
> **on Tab 7**
>
> tfgld4510m000 **-7-** grid-1-tfgld418.fitr-8-filter-value-control-widget

I want to create locator irrespective of its tab position so I created xpath

```
.//*[contains(@id,'grid-1-tfgld418.fitr-8-filter-value-control-widget')]
```

But the issue here is if both tabs are open and I want to click on the field in tab 7 this XPath also detects field in tab 3.

Can you please help me with a solution, so that I can access the field irrespective of tab location.

Comment: So what is the exact `issue with this is id becomes dynamic for every field w.r.t. its tab location`? What are your exact manual steps which you are trying to automate?

Comment: Consider I have two tabs... in tab1 id for save button is 'XXX-1-save' and on tab2 is 'XXX-2-save'... now I want to click on save button in tab2... if u use xpath .//*[contains(@id='save')]... it detects both locators on tab1 and 2.. and throws element is not clickable as control is on tab2.. I hope it explains the issue..

Comment: No, using `xpath .//*[contains(@id='save')]` shouldn't detect both locators on `tab1 and 2`. Selenium's focus is still on page `1`. You need to transfer `Selenium`'s focus to `tab2`. A quick view into your code block may help us to diagnose where you are exactly stuck.

Comment: yes it is.. as both locators are on same page but different tab anyways I got the solution... Get the tab number using getattribute and pass it to xpath.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create dynamic xpath and pass the value as per you required

```
int a = 7;
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tfgld4510m000 -"+a+"- grid-1-tfgld418.fitr-8-filter-value-control-widget']"));
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I tried this before.. and its working but I am using Hybrid Framework which reads keywords and data from excel.. so problem with this method is I am already fetching lot of data like customer, item etc to this keyword method. So I want to avoid fetching tab no. and create generalized xpath so that it should work regardless tab sequence..

Comment: Is there any attribute present on page which can define this attribute for you. Example: if you URL or any other attribute can return you Tab number then just need to pass that value in your int . so dynamically your xpath will be build

Comment: you can use getAttribute method and get the value in string and then using spilt method you can extarct the tab number .. now just pass it to int variable after type cast

Comment: You can add you HTML code in question so I can see where from we can extract the value for you